# slideToggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need some help with .toogle function: my proble is that i need that this function do the same thing by click on two different button;
this is my html code:

```
<div id="popup_prova">
    <div id="contentElencoProva">
    <span>Elenco Prove:</span>
    <form action="responseregistrodocente" method="post">
    <ul id="elencoProve">
<li><input type="radio" name="provaSelected" value="3" checked> <span>Id prova: 3 tipo [scritto/orale]: O conoscenza: Esame</span></li>
<li><input type="radio" name="provaSelected" value="4"> <span>Id prova: 4 tipo [scritto/orale]: O conoscenza: Esame</span></li>
</ul><p class="submitProve"><button type="button" name="creaProva">Crea Prova</button><button type="button" name="modificaProva">Mostra/Nascondi Dettagli Prova</button> <button type="button" name="eliminaProva">Elimina Prova</button>
</p><p class="infoVoto"><span id="info_Voto"></span>
<span><input type="text" name="voto"></span></p>
<p class="submitVoto"><input type="submit" name="modificaVoto" value="Modifica Voto"> <input type="submit" name="eliminaVoto" value="Elimina Voto"></p> </form>
    </div>
<div id="gestioneProva">
<span id="titleProva"></span>
<form id="f_creaProva" action="">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Scegli il tipo di prova: 
    <select name="s_creaProva">
    <option label="Scritto" value="S"></option>
    <option label="Orale" selected value="O"></option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Scrivi i requisiti degli studenti [max 80 caratteri]<span id="counter1"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><textarea id="requisiti" rows="4" cols="35"></textarea></td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Scrivi le abilit&agrave; degli studenti [max 80 caratteri]<span id="counter2"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" ><textarea id="abilita"  rows="4" cols="35"></textarea></td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Invia"><input type="reset" name="resettaProva" value="Cancella"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>


</div>

</div>
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    //CREA PROVA VISUALIZZA IL CAMPO PER CREARE UNA NUOVA PROVA CHE ESISTE SEMPRE

    $("button[name='creaProva']").on("click",function(event){
        $("input[name='resettaProva']").trigger('click');
        $("#titleProva").html("Creazione di una nuova Prova");
        $("#gestioneProva").slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    //MODIFICA e NASCONDI LE INFORMAZIONI DI UNA PROVA
    //.on scatena l'evento ogni qual volta esiste il pulsante in maniera dinamica anche se il pulsante non esiste ancora
    $("button[name='modificaProva']").on("click",function(){
        $("#titleProva").html("Prova attualmente selezionata: <input type=\"text\" name=\"idProva\" value=\""+$("input[name='provaSelected']:checked").val()+"\"readonly>");
        $("#gestioneProva").slideToggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
        });
    $("input[name='provaSelected']").on("change",function(){
        $("#gestioneProva").hide();
        event.stopPropagation();
        });



});
</script>
```

now when i click on button "creaProva" .slidetoggle() works fine and show me the "div gestioneProva" but it doesn't work when i click on button modificaProva.

in my css i have also the display none only on div gestioneProva

Thx a lot for help!!!

Comment: You're not declaring the `event` arguments of the handlers you bind to `click` on `button[name='modificaProva']` and `input[name='provaSelected']`. There should be an error in the console when you try calling `event.stopPropagation()` in these handlers.

Comment: there will not be error since `event` object is available globally,at least in IE and chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the event argument in this line :

```
$("button[name='modificaProva']").on("click",function(){
```

change it to  :

```
$("button[name='modificaProva']").on("click",function(event){
```